# Flipping pose isn't working

Tags: pose-mode

when I copy a pose (ctrl + c) and then flip it with this shortcut(shift+ctrl+c) the I see some weird result don't know why.

[image]

then this happens after I've pasted it

[image]

You can check the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10O3fTxd4vqewUMz-C3DlTw43K1EMtTXE) if you want. I've uploaded it in my google drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bone "Arm.R" have wrong rotate.[image]

So,simply to fix it you should delete this bone and all hand bone and add new bone by symmetrize from left side.
[image]

Comment: you're right, but do you know why is not possible to move anything with the 3D manipulator? (at least on my computer)

Comment: sorry @moonboots I do not understand your question, maybe give me more details?

Comment: I have a bug with this file, I can take an object and move it with G but I can't grab the 3D manipulator (XYZ widget), I don't understand why, if you have any idea I'm interested

Comment: @moonboots i sorry that i ccant help because it work for me. Have you ever tried to check on another computer

Comment: that's weird, no I don't have another computer, ok, thanks anyway

Comment: oh ok someone has found on another forum, I have to go View > Align View > View Lock Clear. Don't know what it's for though