# Cannot flip my pose properly

Tags: pose-mode

when I copy a pose (ctrl + c) and then flip it with this shortcut(shift+ctrl+c) the I see some weird result don't know why.

[image]

then this happens after I've pasted it

[image]

You can check the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10O3fTxd4vqewUMz-C3DlTw43K1EMtTXE) if you want. I've uploaded it in my google drive.

Comment: I have answered your post there: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118982/flipping-pose-isnt-working. Do not duplicate it.

Comment: you're right, but do you know why is not possible to move anything with the 3D manipulator? (at least on my computer)